# how to detect whether function called from console or via callback

Tags: matlab, callback

I've inherited a large function which both processes data and generates a graphics window with a set of callback keypress functions, most of which use the original function to do some reprocessing.  Is there any builtin MATLAB function which can be used (inside the main function) to test whether the code's been called via callback as opposed to a console command?

The existing function generates a variable called `is_callback` and sets or resets that value when specific portions of code which drive the graphics are executed.  I guess that works, but was hoping for a more direct method.

Comment: You might be able to get the information you need by using [`dbstack`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html), but I don't know if it will work in your specific situation.

Comment: @ThomasIbbotson yeah, I noticed a similar suggestion on the MathExchange forums.  People had varying success with it.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I believe you'd be better off to separate the data processing functions (Model) from the displaying part (View) and the "online" configuration via pressed keys (Controller).

Comment: @CST-Link like I said, I inherited this :-( .  And due to the size of the data involved, it pretty much has to get processed "on demand" when generating a new graph.